# Why were the Hosts on the Max Capricorn cruise liner programmed to follow The Doctor's orders?

Tags: doctor-who

In [Doctor Who: Voyage of the Damned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyage_of_the_Damned_(Doctor_Who)), why did the Hosts start to follow the Doctor's orders?

Did the Doctor reprogram them himself, or were they programmed to take orders from the nearest organism after Capricorn's death? Logically, the Doctor shouldn't have any such authority at all - he is not a Capricorn Cruise Line employee. That authority should, in theory have gone straight to the Midshipman.

Comment: “logically, the Doctor shouldn't have any such authority at all - he is not a cruise line employee” — logically, there’s rarely anyone you want in authority more than the Doctor.

Comment: Sheer force of personality

Comment: He faked authority until someone believed him. Like always

Comment: It's not really mentioned in the commentary; http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p020brqn

Answer (score 3):

If you read through the [show script](http://leethomson.myzen.co.uk/Doctor_Who/Doctor_Who_4x00_-_Voyage_of_the_Damned.pdf), it's fairly obviously that they're trying to convey that everything that *can* go wrong *has* gone wrong. Not only is the ship careening toward the ground but all of the senior crew are dead and many of the passengers are trapped with no chance of escape. Everyone is yelling for the Doctor to help.

With Max, the Captain, the senior Engineer and the rest of the crew either disabled or dead, Midshipman Frame is theoretically in command but it should be pretty clear, even to a couple of malfunctioning robots that by sitting on the floor begging for assistance, he's *voluntarily deferring his authority* to the Doctor:

> 94 INT. BRIDGE - NIGHT 94
>
> SLOW MOTION. SOUNDLESS, music only.
>
> PRAC EXPLOSIONS from the computer banks, beautiful in slowmotion,
>   sparks arcing, with MIDSHIPMAN FRAME desperate, trying to use the
>   controls, but having to shield himself.
>
> **And though there's no sound, he is yelling 'Doctor! Doctor, help me!' Over and over again...**

It also appears that the Hosts have been crudely reprogrammed (presumably by Max) to accept his orders even where they contradict the Host's primary function of serving the crew and passengers. Under the circumstances, it's hardly surprising that they would revert to their normal function after Max's death:

> **CHIEF STEWARD:** *That's eight of them now, on the blink. One woman, she asked the Host to fix her necklace, it almost broke her neck. In
>   First Class!*
>
> **ENGINEER:** *I've been over the robotics, nothing. **Like something's got into them, some sort of bug.***

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I think its clear in the episode, but you have to go back to why the angels took him to Max in the first place

> DOCTOR: No! No, no, no, no. That wasn't a question either. Blimey. One question left. One question. **So, you've been given orders to kill the survivors but survivors must therefore be passengers or staff**, but not me. **I'm not a passenger. I'm not staff**. Go on, scan me. You must have bio-records. No such person on board. **I don't exist, therefore you can't kill me**. Therefore, I'm a stowaway, and stowaways should be arrested and taken to the nearest figure of authority. And I reckon the nearest figure of authority is on deck thirty one. Final question. Am I right?
>
> HOST: Information. Correct.
>
> DOCTOR: Brilliant. Take me to your leader. I've always wanted to say that.

When Max dies those instructions to kill passengers or staff still applies (we know it means both as they have already killed staff too), he didn't remove the the program or tell them to kill the Doctor (well he did but then decided to listen to the Doctor, which stopped them killing him), so they still don't know what to do with him

Now the highest authority on the ship that is NOT passengers or staff, is the Doctor. They default to him because they are under orders to kill everyone else, that means he is the only person left who can give them instructions now. The doctor says this when they fly him to the bridge

> the hosts automatically directed to the next highest authority: me

**Summary**

I think the confusion comes from the 2 scenes not being close enough together. The Doctor is literally the only person on the ship they are not allowed to kill now, in a ship where you are under orders to kill everyone except one person, that one person is the only one they are allowed to listen to after Max died

Answer (score -1):

The Doctor tells Alonzo after Capricorn was killed that,

> the hosts automatically directed to the next highest authority: **me**

This was told to Alonzo after the hosts helped the Doctor ascend to the bridge.
This gave the Doctor the ability to order them around. Convenient.

> Allons-y Alonzo!

Comment: I'm struggling to see how this answers the question in any meaningful sense.

Comment: @Richard I thought you didn't know the information provided. How was it not useful.

Comment: I'm not arguing that the info isn't potentially useful, just that it doesn't answer the question (e.g. **Why** do they consider him an authority).

Comment: @Richard Oh. I see your point now. Sorry about that.